# How to make changes to os.environ dict available application wide

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

In my app engine/django application's `main.app`, where the control is actually handled to the django WSGI handler, I set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as below:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

but when I try try to get it in some other view:

```
y=os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
```

It gives me key error. How can I set the value application wide?

Comment: If os.environ is thread local per request, you might have to register the settings module at the beginning of your handler (inside the get or post method). Worth a shot.

Comment: I am using django and not webapp2. So you want me to register this  module in each of the django views I am using it... Is there not a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define environment variables in your app.yaml file which are set for every request. See:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#env_variables

Comment: This is a great suggestion, this really helped

Answer (score 3):

When using the Python 2.7 runtime, os.environ is actually a thread-local dict that shadows the WSGI environment.  One thing you can try: set it in appengine_config.py.

Comment: Anand's answer is much better.